# Sizing and centering box element in Bulma

Tags: bulma

I have a login modal in which I have a box, with the following CSS structure:

```
<div class="modal" v-bind:class="{ 'is-active': isActive }">
    <div class="modal-background">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="box">
            // content 
            // content 
            // content 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to change the size of my box to a certain width. If I set for example `.box { width: 600px };` the box size grows, but it doesn't automatically center itself -- the width just gets added on to the right. Is there any way I can change the box size, while keeping it horizontally centered?

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do is wrap the box inside a column. And give the column which ever size you need the box to be.

```
<div className="column is-one-third">
      <div className="box">
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i have not encountered any form of doing this.
The other way you can tackle this is by using columns.

```
.columns
    .column.is-one-quarter
        .box One quarter
    .column.is-one-quarter 
        .box One quarter This box would have a reduced size, for it is contained in 1 quarter
    .column.is-one-quarter 
        .box One quarter
```

Checkout this link https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/sizes/